# Running feeds in order

Tags: 7, rules, feeds

I just ran into a situation where I need to run three imports, one after another using the same file providing successful import. Does anyone know how to do this? I looked briefly at Feeds rules but I don't think that will work unless I'm missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a small custom module to add your own queue:

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.queue.inc/group/queue/7

Then use your callback to run each item through feeds.